# How i can import my date to database incule \ and ,?

Tags: php, sql, database

I have problem when i try import my database beacuse all \ do not import into the database. For example (-2) in sql file will be (-2) in my database. How i can solution my problem ?

This is my first record who i try add

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dawidek (
    `pytanie` VARCHAR(551) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `numerzadania` VARCHAR(18) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `a` VARCHAR(104) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `b` VARCHAR(83) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `c` VARCHAR(103) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `d` VARCHAR(82) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `poprawna` VARCHAR(108) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `rozwionzanie` VARCHAR(3998) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `rok_id` INT,
    `typ_id` INT,
    `Wydawca_1stara_matura_2operon_3_nowaera_4_nowa_matura` VARCHAR(1) CHARACTER SET utf8
);
INSERT INTO dawidek VALUES
    ("Wskaż nierówność, która opisuje sumę przedziałów zaznaczonych na osi liczbowej.",
"Zadanie 1. (1pkt)","\(|x-2|\gt4\)","\(|x-2|\lt4\)","\(|x-4|\lt2\)","\(|x-4|\gt2\)",
"A",
"Zadanie to można rozwiązać obliczając każdą z nierówności podaną w odpowiedziach. Jeśli chcemy obliczyć to w sposób matematyczny, to możemy skorzystać z interpretacji geometrycznej zbioru rozwiązań nierówności. Na początek musimy wyznaczyć środek odcinka o końcach w punkcie \(-2\) oraz \(6\), a będzie to:
$$a=\frac{-2+6}{2}=\frac{4}{2}=2$$ Wyznaczony punkt \(a=2\) jest odległy od punktów końcowych (\(-2\) oraz \(6\)) o cztery jednostki. Skoro przedziały idą do plus/minus nieskończoności to zaznaczony zbiór jest zbiorem liczb odległych od punktu \(a=2\) o ponad \(4\) jednostki. Stąd też poszukiwaną nierównością jest \(|x-2|\gt4\).",
1,
1,
NULL);
```

I try to use " ' and ` and never i see \ symbols in database. Its important, beacuse it is use by Matjax in my website.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your other tech stack and the use of backticks on column names I'm guessing this is mysql

[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) has useful things to say about backslashes. I personally would recommend you enable ANSI_QUOTES and NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES, put your existing strings in single quotes `'` and it'll work out

If you don't want to enable "no backslash escapes" you'll have to double up your backslashes to `\\` because any char that follows a single `\` will either be interpreted as a special character (eg if you write `\b` it will become a BACKSPACE character) or it will be a literal character if the single char following the backslash has no special meaning (e.g `\B` is just a capital B) -  **either way you lose the backslash**

Comment: Its working, thanks, if i have simmilar problem with $$ what i can do ?

Comment: Ask another question with the updated relevant code in it. Don't forget to click the grey tick on the left hand side of this answer if it's what you implemented; it marks the question as answered so other people know